# É possível acessar uma variável compartilhada com outra thread sem problema de concorrência?

Tags: java

Tenho esse código

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();

public void RunOperation(){
    myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < ReallyHighNumber; i++) {
                myList.add(SimulationStep(i));
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}

public List<Object> GetData(){
    return myList;
}
```

Eu quero retornar valores parciais enquanto a thread executa, uma vez que o número de repetições pode ficar muito grande. Uma das soluções foi rodar a operação 100 vezes após cada GetData(), porém não é o apropriado.

Tentei usar variável volátil e atômica, porém não sei se foi um uso errado, mas continuou dando problema de concorrência ao chamar o GetData().

O método synchronized com wait() e notify() não resolveu também, pois ele espera que a thread termine o loop.

Alguém sabe qual método ou caminho usar para resolver esse problema ?

Obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score 1):

Você não especificou o problema de concorrência que está acontecendo, mas imagino que seja o acesso simultâneo por duas threads à variável `myList`.

Experimente inicializar a variável assim e veja se resolve:

```
List<Object> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Quanto ao uso do bloco `synchronized`, ele funciona se você colocá-lo apenas dentro do `for` e dentro do `getData()`.